# SSRS Report - Dynamic Parameters causing awful slowness

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, reporting-services, parameters, dataset

I've built an SSRS Report with a series of parameters and data sets a user specifies a season (first parameter). There are several data sets -- see below.

The first is a procedure: called LRP_Weekly_Stats returns 9 fields (including, location, eventdata, option, season, and a few others.

The second data set pulls - all the distinct seasons from a view - that gets sent to the parameter drop down. `select distinct season from myview` it shows/returns just `season`.

2 additional data set exists it reads

```
select distinct location from myview where my season = parameter season
```

and

```
 select distinct option from myview where my season = parameter season
```

each of these data sets return `location` and `option` respectively.

[image]

We can't build this as 1 single data set because each of the 5 locations has each of the 4 options associated with and the data being returned gets multiplied by itself.

Data in my view looks like this

```
Location         option
-------------------------
Location1        option1
Location1        option2
Location1        option3
Location1        option4
Location1        option5
Location2        option1
Location2        option2
Location2        option3
Location2        option4
Location3        option1
Location3        option2
Location3        option4
Location3        option5
etc.
```

In order for the parameters to show each location once and each option 1 for the parameter drop down we do two separate queries.

I didn't build the view and can't adjust it and even if i could the data is such that each location can have each option.

so my two data sets each return the distinct list of possible locations and/or options by season.

in the parameters in the SSRS report the set up looks like this:

[image]

so the data coming in to my parameter is pulled from my data set. for each of the three parameters. location and option_1 and option_2. The code itself runs in under 5 seconds however because of all this linkage it takes a good 30+ minutes to run the report. This is completely unacceptable (and I can't remove the drop down data because the users need it).

Any advice about how to streamline this or make it more efficient. Please help.

Comment: Can you skip using the view and DISTINCT and go directly to queries that query for location by season and option by season from the location and option lookup tables in the database?

Comment: Sadly no, I put in a request to get access to those tables, but so far denied.   I have to work with this view because it pulls the data from 4 different databases into one central location.

Comment: Short of you being able to write stored procedures, created specifically for your report, there isn't going to be a lot that you can... :(

Comment: So your user selects "season" from an unrestricted dropdown parameter list first, then selects "location" and "option" from two dropdown parameter lists that are restricted by the selected season, and finally runs the report, and it's the final report that takes 30+ minutes to run, correct?

Comment: @Brian yes you are correct.

Comment: From your response to Brian's comment I can only assume the main report dataset appears to be the problem, can you edit your question and post the dataset query for that.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I've added more data to the ticket/question. The first dataset is a procedure it returns a series of columns that get populated in the report.  The remaining data sets (in the added screenshot) each return one piece of information - that is then used to populate the dropdowns for the parameters to push into the main dataset1 (procedure)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your reply in the comments on your initial question, it looks to me like the issue is either in the report procedure itself, or possibly a rendering issue.  I would look at performance tuning the main report queries.  And I'm afraid I can't be more specific than that without knowing a lot more details about your report's architecture.

Comment: the procedure actually works well - it runs in 4 seconds for the same parameter set that the report itself takes 30+ minute to run. Considering the amount of data its looking at (a lot of data) that is a good time. There isn't much to add/tune in the procedure itself -- but i will edit the ticket and place more code/datasets into it.

Comment: Put a profiler trace on the query when you run it from SSRS and verify that the procedure performance is still in the ~5 second range - performance in SSMS doesn't always reflect performance from SSRS.  You might want to add a set of internal variables, with assignments from the associated parameters, to defeat SQL Server parameter sniffing.

If you run the report twice in succession with the EXACT same parameters, how does it perform?  Doing this test takes the SQL Server call out of the picture.